# How to check file transfer completion in unix

Tags: unix, file-io

How can I check file transfer completion in unix
e.g. 2GB file is getting transferd and before openning it I would like check weather the file is still under process or not.

Comment: How do you exactly transfer it? Via the file browser, `cp`, `scp`, `rsync`?

Comment: that i am not sure. because the file gets transferd from another system.

Comment: By what means? Do you use some network share like samba or dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sync`. That way you can be sure that any write operations are finished.

Comment: can you please tell me how to run the sync.

Comment: Open terminal and enter `sync` command. When it returns the file transfer should be complete. But it won't help if the file is coming from remote system.

Answer (score 0):

If you control somehow the sending process, you should copy also a signature file (which is short). Before opening the file you check the signature is OK.

Use these commands on sender(local_host)

```
scp large_file remote_host:/remote_folder && \
md5sum large_file > large_file.md5 && \
scp large_file.md5 remote_host:/remote_folder
```

Use these commands on receiver(remote_host)

```
nok=1
while [ $nok -eq 1 ] ; do
  [ /remote_folder/large_file ] && \
    [ -f /remote_folder/large_file.md5 ] && \
    mdcsum -c /remote_folder/large_file && nok = 0 || \
    sleep 1
done
```